# How to test click commands that expect files

Tags: python, pytest, python-click

I have a click command that does something with a file:

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument("file", type=click.File("r"))
def foo(file):
    print(file.read())
```

And I'd like to test it without creating temporary files, but I don't know which path to give the runner and can't find examples on the web. Something like this would be nice:

```py
from click.testing import CliRunner

from magic_lib import magic_file

def test_foo():
    runner = CliRunner()
    fake_file = magic_file("Hello, world!")
    result = runner.invoke(foo, [fake_file.location])
    assert result.output == "Hello, world!\n"
```

Any way I can make `click.File` understand where I want it to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pyfakefs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfakefs/). The [usage](https://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/master/usage.html) depends on your testing framework; it's easiest to use with [pytest](https://pytest.org/en/latest/) because it automatically provides an `fs` fixture:

```
def test_foo(fs):
    fake_file = fs.create_file('/foo/bar', contents="Hello, world!")

    runner = CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(foo, [fake_file.path])
    assert result.output == "Hello, world!\n"
```

P.S.: Because the `print` in `foo` adds a newline, the file has to be created without `\n` at the end for the test to work.

Comment: "pyfakefs automatically adds a newline to the file" I think that's from the click function, since it calls `print`.

Comment: Funny thing, I just found an example solution using `click`'s own test object [here](https://github.com/mandeep/Travis-Encrypt/blob/4dd534c4672410a74bd29ec010c8d945f6d323cb/tests/test_cli.py#L52-L75), but yours is way leaner and allows me to re-use my invoke-fixture, so I won't bother writing an answer featuring that one.

Comment: @Arne I think you should reconsider it. IMO The optimal solution is to use `isolated_filesystem`

Comment: @FcknGioconda why do you think click's is better? As far as I can see, pyfakefs does the same thing, but once I learned it I can also use it in all my other projects that don't use click.